# Deploy opportunity change from sandbox to production

Tags: deployment, sandbox, production

For a project the client has multiple changes including apex files, some metadata changes, and a few custom object changes. But they have also modified the Opportunity table and added two new fields.

I was able to add everything to a change set, except the opportunity. For opportunity can I add it to change set? Or is it because it's a Standard object it can't be added to the change set?

I am a little bit new to deployment via change set so apologies if I am missing something obvious.

Comment: what parts of the opportunity object are you trying to move?

Comment: You can't add an entire object to a change set. Instead you will have to add fields or modified fields 1 by 1 to the change set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add the entire Opportunity object, but you can add individual fields. You'll find them under Custom Fields in the Add Components interface. You can also use the View Dependencies button on the Change Set to find all related components that can be deployed, including those custom fields (if referenced in code or other metadata).